# Material UI, row background color with different cell background

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI table in React 18 and each cell has a different background color. However this will break the hover style on the row and I am not able to find a solution.

Just to be clear you can check here what I want to achieve: https://explain.depesz.com/s/dFJ2

If you hover on the table's row you can see that the color just gets darker.

How can I achieve this using React and Material UI? Is there a simple way?

From my Cell component I can set a different color for when it is in hover state, but this will work for single Cell hover not for the entire Row

```
export const MyCustomCell = (props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <TableCell
            style={{
                backgroundColor: getCellBackground(props)
            }}
            sx={{
                "&.MuiTableCell-root:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: getCellBackgroundOnHover(props)
                }
            }}
        >
            {betterTiming(prop)}
        </TableCell>
    )
}
```

```
 <TableRow
            role="checkbox"
            sx={{
                '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border: 0},
                // "&.MuiTableRow-root:hover": {
                //     backgroundColor: "pink !important"
                // }
            }}
            tabIndex={-1}
        >
</TableRow>
```

EDIT: **The color is computed dynamically from props**

Comment: You can add create a variant adding style override, normally and even for the case of having a dynamic color coming from prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find any solution by searching on google and I ended up by just using hover state in React

```
const [rowHovered, setRowHovered] = React.useState(false);

   const handleRowHover = () => {
        setRowHovered(true);
    };

    const handleRowLeave = () => {
        setRowHovered(false);
    };

    return (
        <TableRow
            role="checkbox"
            onMouseEnter={handleRowHover}
            onMouseLeave={handleRowLeave}
        >
        <MyCustomCell hovered={rowHovered} />
</TableRow>
```

```
export const MyCustomCell = (props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    return (
        <TableCell
            style={{
                backgroundColor: getCellBackgroundColor(props, props.hovered)
            }}
        >
            ...
        </TableCell>
    )
}
```

And then `getCellBackgroundColor` will just calculate the color according to my specific business logic.